# Make Google Marker follow road

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm currently using Google Maps to display data from over 500 vehicles on a map. Currently, vehicles are updated on average every 60 seconds. I currently use some JavaScript/jQuery to animate each marker from its old position to its new position.

Because the data isn't coming in very frequently it often means that each marker would animate across many buildings, rivers, lakes etc. What I'd like to do is have these markers follow the road, however I'm worried that in doing so it could become expensive.

I see that the Google Maps Directions API would allow me to do this. If I calculate the route from the marker's old position to its new position it would split the route up into many different lines and I could have the markers animate across them. However, with 500 vehicles updating every minute, that's 500 direction requests every minute. Somehow I don't think I'd even survive on the Google Maps for Business API.

If anyone has any ideas as to how I could do this without spending billions, I'd appreciate it.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems to me that you would only query the Direction API once for each 500 vehicles as long as the destination never changes. You may still run up against API rate limiting nonetheless.

You're going to need to reduce your set of 500 down to something more manageable. I would probably start by only performing animations/calculations on markers that are only immediately visible within the given map viewport. You would still need to update all marker positions in case a marker is about to come into your viewport, but you don't necessarily need to manage this with an actual `google.maps.Marker` object for each vehicle. You could instead keep track of positions in a separate data structure so you're not having to constantly draw to the map.

As an aside, you may also want to explore clustering options for your markers as having more than a dozen or so on screen at once becomes visually unmanageable.

Comment: Considering the difficulty of the situation I'm in I think that's a great answer. Thanks very much.

Comment: Yes, group vehicles to show ~200 on the map, then I think you'll be fine in ters of usage limits. BTW you might be non-compliant with  https://developers.google.com/maps/terms#section_10_12 (c.iii) if your app isn't public.

Comment: @miguev This app is public, but thanks for pointing it out. :)

Comment: @jskidd3: Have the same issue. 
Have implemented clusters to group the markers but unable to make vehicle follow the map with real time rotation. It follows the straight line without rotation. (Have given the custom image to marker)
Could you please share the code snippet over jsfiddle on how have you used Directions API to show the real time route on map?